# Unable to create a google cast container using Obj-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-cast-sdk

I'm trying to build a sample app using the GoogleCast sdk. I'm stuck at the first step.

For some weird reason, I'm unable to create the cast container in Obj-c.

I'm not using the pods. I downloaded the frameworks and added them to the project.

Here is the method I call in AppDelegate didFinishLaunching method:

```
-(void)setupChromeCastContainer {

   GCKDiscoveryCriteria *discoveryCriteria = [[GCKDiscoveryCriteria alloc]initWithApplicationID:kGCKDefaultMediaReceiverApplicationID];
    GCKCastOptions *options = [[GCKCastOptions alloc]initWithDiscoveryCriteria:discoveryCriteria];
    [GCKCastContext setSharedInstanceWithOptions:options];
    [GCKCastContext sharedInstance].useDefaultExpandedMediaControls = YES;

    UIStoryboard *st = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *nav = [st instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"navVc"];
    GCKUICastContainerViewController * containerVc = [[GCKCastContext sharedInstance]createCastContainerControllerForViewController:nav];
    containerVc.miniMediaControlsItemEnabled = YES;
    self.window.rootViewController = containerVc;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [self setupChromeCastContainer];
    return YES;
}
```

In the above method, `GCKUICastContainerViewController * containerVc` is returning nil. And also the nav is NOT nil, so I'm passing the valid object.

I'm unable to find why `createCastContainerControllerForViewController` returns nil or in which case it returns nil.

My environment is Xcode 11.3.1.

I even tried to add the cast button to the nav bar, and cast button code returns nil too.

```
GCKUICastButton *castButton = [[GCKUICastButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 24, 24)];  //castButton  returns nill
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check to see if nav was nil? Also is containerVc nil or is it actually uninitialized?

What you have looks similar to the [sample](https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-ios/blob/master/CastVideos-objc/Classes/AppDelegate.m) so I would see if there is something going on in the storyboard.

I believe the main cases for when the `GCKUICastContainerViewController` returns nil is either when the options are not set on `GCKCastContext` or when a bad view controller is provided.